# Add to instance variable another variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such empty class object (hash):

```
@art_concret
```

i need to add to this variable some another....
i try:

```
@art_concret = @articles #@articles.find_all{|item| item.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').include?(search.upcase) }
@art_concret = @articles_oem
@art_concret.uniq
```

also something like:

```
art = []
art << @articles #@articles.find_all{|item| item.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').include?(search.upcase) }
art << @articles_oem
@art_concret = art.uniq.flatten! #| @articles
@art_concret
```

this didn't work if i need to push in @art_concret two another (but with same structure) objects?
how then?

**upd**
For example just:

```
@a = {:a => 1}
@b = {:a => 2}
```

just how to do that @c will have @a + @b = {{:a => 1}, {:a => 2}}     ... just split them

@c = @a + @b - with one test it work's

Comment: "will this work" - why don't you just try? It would probably took you less time than composing this question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this didn't work.... Did you read  `If not, how then?` This is not working!

Comment: Then improve your question: add actual data, remove irrelevant details. Help us help you.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i improved q

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so what, do you have ideas?

Comment: That's not much of an improvement. First of all, what didn't work. Second, make a snippet that we can run and see the problem by ourselves.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev see upd

Comment: `{{:a => 1}, {:a => 2}}` is not a valid ruby construct I know of.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this is pseudo

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it take a while.... why? You said that it is easy

Comment: I asked for a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem. You supplied some pseudo-code instead. So I gave up.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev hm..... if you didn't understand pseudo, than you just dodn't get what i asked.... see buru's answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need to merge two hashes? If that's the case, then simply use `merge` method:

```
@a = {:a => 1}
@b = {:b => 2}
@a.merge(@b)
```

=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}

Or, if you hashes have similar keys and you need to perform some action on corresponding values:

```
@a = {:a => 1}
@b = {:a => 2}
@a.merge(@b)­ { |key,v1,v­2| v1 + v2 }
```

=> {:a=>3}